# E-paper display working problem- UC8151D driver

Tags: spi, display

I'm working on e-paper display GDEW0213T5-D product which including UC8151D IC driver.I can communicate with e-paper with SPI interface however there are problems with showing correct things(e.g. temperature value) on the screen.What is the correct algorithm to driving that kind of IC's?In the  example datasheet, there are some info's about proper usage.It includes "init" function as resetting operation, driver "init" function to initilazing driver, and local initialization function as refresh operation.I have also written functions to e-paper screen such as cursoring , putting pixels , chars drawing lines etc.However I'm stuck at initialization, I think I can't initialize the driver correctly.

If there is a UC8151 IC driver which written in C language I will be very appreciated.

Comment: What MCU are you driving it with?  Displays usually include drivers for popular MCUs.

Comment: I'm working on CC430(TI MSP430- RF series). Unfortunately there is no driver for this MCU, even I can't find any example for STM32 MCU's.

Comment: Since any driver's main function is taking commands from its control interface, that thing is documented; you should ask the manufacturer or your electronics distributor for a datasheet that specifies every single SPI command; from there on it *should* be pretty straightforward. Without that, there's a very significant chance it's impossible with the hardware you have. So, get that documentation.